# GNURadio On Raspberry Pi 3 Reports: No module named _osmosdr_swig

Tags: python, gnuradio

I am trying to run a GNURadio flow graph that runs fine on my Windows computer but gives me an error on my Raspberry Pi.
The error is:

No module named _osmosdr_swig

For some reason line feeds in my perfectly formatted text in these entry fields get removed when I post.  The format instructions say, "for linebreak add 2 spaces at end" but I can't get that to work.

I have tried to add a second line feed to each line.  I hope I didn't miss any.

I just don't know enough Python to understand what is happening.

Here is what GNURadio reported:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/pi/Documents/Security/top_block.py", line 28, in 
    import osmosdr

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osmosdr/**init**.py", line 26, in 
    from osmosdr_swig import *

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osmosdr/osmosdr_swig.py", line 21, in 
    _osmosdr_swig = swig_import_helper()

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osmosdr/osmosdr_swig.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_osmosdr_swig')

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
    **import**(name)
ImportError: No module named _osmosdr_swig

Python code snippets from around the traces are:

From top_block.py

25 from gnuradio.eng_option import eng_option

26 from gnuradio.filter import firdes

27 from optparse import OptionParser

28 import osmosdr

29 import sip

From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osmosdr/**init**.py

25 # import swig generated symbols into the osmosdr namespace

26 from osmosdr_swig import *

27

28 # import any pure python here

29 #

From /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osmosdr/osmosdr_swig.py

11 from sys import version_info as _swig_python_version_info

12 if _swig_python_version_info >= (2, 7, 0):

13     def swig_import_helper():

14         import importlib

15         pkg = **name**.rpartition('.')[0]

16         mname = '.'.join((pkg, '_osmosdr_swig')).lstrip('.')

17         try:

18             return importlib.import_module(mname)

19         except ImportError:

20             return importlib.import_module('_osmosdr_swig')

21     _osmosdr_swig = swig_import_helper()

22     del swig_import_helper

23 elif _swig_python_version_info >= (2, 6, 0):

From /usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py

20 def import_module(name, package=None):

21     """Import a module.

22

23     The 'package' argument is required when performing a relative 
import. It

24     specifies the package to use as the anchor point from which to resolve the

25     relative import to an absolute import.

26

27     """

28     if name.startswith('.'):

29         if not package:

30             raise TypeError("relative imports require the 'package' argument")

31         level = 0

32         for character in name:

33             if character != '.':

34                 break

35             level += 1

36         name = _resolve_name(name[level:], package, level)
37     **import**(name)

38     return sys.modules[name]